# unknown datasource properties for springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm following a tutorial about springboot that tells to add the following rows to my **application.properties** file

```
spring.datasource.max-active=10
spring.datasource.max-idle=8
spring.datasource.max-wait=10000
spring.datasource.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=1000
spring.datasource.min-idle=8
spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=1
```

however spring sts marks the rows as "unknown property"

i saw that the "intellisense" feature offers the following (properties with **.tomcat**):

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=10
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=8
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=10000
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=1000
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=8
spring.datasource.tomcat.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=1
```

so i'm wondering if the first set of properties is obsolete, and replaced by the second set

Thanks

Comment: The sets are the same, so not sure what you are trying to compare..

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for pointing that out. i've corrected the upper block of properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formar one is more standard props from boot and later one is implementation specific, e.g if you are using tomcat-jdbc then *.tomcat.* props are correct, see for more details:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceProperties.java

Comment: Thanks Sagar, i'm not 100% sure if this is it

i see that i have dependencies 
i have other spring.data-source settings that did not receive any alert, as follows.

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/boat
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver


but only the mentioned block settings was not recognized by STS (highlighted as "unknown property")

Also, i'm running the spring boot application with the settings as in the above block, I get no warning , which is strange if these were completely unrecognized

Comment: Which version of spring boot you are using?

Comment: version 1.5.1.RELEASE